# Getting a parameter from view in the controllers index

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have the following code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $view = $this->_getParam('view');
    echo $view;
}
```

This does not print out whatever I enter after view/ unless I put index/ in front of of e.g. /index/view .  Notice stackoverflow doesn't have 'index' in it's URL when we are looking at /questions/3123[any id will do].

How are they omitting the 'index' when I have to include it? I'm using Zend Framework.

Answer (score 2):

See: [Zend Framework Router - Usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.usage)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to follow the generic url structure, where /controller/action/paramId/paramValue, you need to set up routes. In your config, you could put:

```
resources.router.routes.question.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.question.route = "question/:id"
resources.router.routes.question.defaults.controller = "question"
resources.router.routes.question.defaults.action = "index"
```

A url of /question/123 should now map to the index action of the Question controller and the param id would have the value 123.